# Elixir Struct Access Efficiency

Tags: elixir

I am implementing a sorting algorithm to sort a collection of structs. I need to sort the collection on the value of a particular key in each struct. I can hard code the key into the function, but I'd like to generalize it. As you can see below, the specialized implementation is 3x faster than the generalized.

Is there a more efficient way to get the value of a key in a struct than `defp get_value(x, key), do: get_in(x, [Access.key(key)])`? Which comes from the [docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Access.html#key/2).

**Specialized**

```
defmodule QuickSort do
  def qsort([]) do
    []
  end
  def qsort([pivot | rest]) do
    {left, right} = Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> x.key < pivot.key end)
    qsort(left) ++ [pivot] ++ qsort(right)
  end
end




iex(74)> Benchwarmer.benchmark fn -> QuickSort.qsort(collection, :key) end                                            
*** #Function<20.52032458/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5> ***
2.5 sec      3 iterations   863742.34 μs/op
```

**Generalized**

```
defmodule QuickSort do
  def qsort(collection, key \\ nil)
  def qsort([], _) do
    []
  end
  def qsort([pivot | rest], key) do
    {left, right} = Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> get_value(x, key) < get_value(pivot, key) end)
    qsort(left, key) ++ [pivot] ++ qsort(right, key)
  end

  defp get_value(x, key), do: get_in(x, [Access.key(key)])
end




iex(79)> Benchwarmer.benchmark fn -> QuickSort.qsort(collection, :key) end
*** #Function<20.52032458/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5> ***
3.1 sec      1 iterations   3180784.0 μs/op
```

Comment: How about `defp get_value(x, key), do: x[key]`?

Comment: It throws an error saying that my struct `does not implement the Access behaviour`

Comment: Ah, it's a struct. This should work then: `defp get_value(x, key), do: Map.get(x, key)`. Instead of a separate function, you can also just put this in the `Enum.partition`'s fn: `Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> Map.get(x, key) < Map.get(pivot, key) end)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map.get` will get you pretty close to hardcoded key, but it's not as fast as hardcoded key as Erlang most likely does some extra optimizations for those. Here's your two versions against `Map.get`:

```
defmodule Thing do
  defstruct [:key]
end

defmodule QuickSortDotKey do
  def qsort([]), do: []
  def qsort([pivot | rest]) do
    {left, right} = Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> x.key < pivot.key end)
    qsort(left) ++ [pivot] ++ qsort(right)
  end
end

defmodule QuickSortAccessKey do
  def qsort([], _), do: []
  def qsort([pivot | rest], key) do
    {left, right} = Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> get_value(x, key) < get_value(pivot, key) end)
    qsort(left, key) ++ [pivot] ++ qsort(right, key)
  end

  defp get_value(x, key), do: get_in(x, [Access.key(key)])
end

defmodule QuickSortMapGet do
  def qsort([], _), do: []
  def qsort([pivot | rest], key) do
    {left, right} = Enum.partition(rest, fn(x) -> Map.get(x, key) < Map.get(pivot, key) end)
    qsort(left, key) ++ [pivot] ++ qsort(right, key)
  end
end

defmodule Bench do
  use Benchfella

  bench ".key", [list: gen()] do
    QuickSortDotKey.qsort(list)
  end

  bench "Access.key", [list: gen()] do
    QuickSortAccessKey.qsort(list, :key)
  end

  bench "Map.get", [list: gen()] do
    QuickSortMapGet.qsort(list, :key)
  end

  defp gen, do: for _ <- 1..10000, do: %Thing{key: :rand.uniform}

  # Tests
  list = for _ <- 1..10000, do: %Thing{key: :rand.uniform}
  sorted = Enum.sort_by(list, &(&1.key))
  true = sorted == QuickSortDotKey.qsort(list)
  true = sorted == QuickSortAccessKey.qsort(list, :key)
  true = sorted == QuickSortMapGet.qsort(list, :key)
end
```

Output:

```
## Bench
benchmark n iterations   average time
.key               100   15572.13 µs/op
Map.get            100   23042.38 µs/op
Access.key          50   60898.12 µs/op
```

Answer (score 2):

`get_in(..., [Access.key(key)])` does a lot of things most of which you don't need in this simple example. It's used for accessing nested structures so it needs to iterate over an array of functions (not to mention that you need to create those functions with `Access.key`). Not surprisingly it's much slower.

`Map.get` is calling `Map.fetch` first, then checking if an element exists to substitute it with default if it's not. Again, some extra code.

In my observation the closest thing you can get to `.key` is `Map.fetch`. Or if you want to go low-level `:maps.find(key, map)` (not much advantage over `Map.fetch` though).

The reason why `.key` is so efficient is because it's compiled directly into BEAM bytecode without calling external functions.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Elixir 1.12, which is not the latest as of this date (but the one supported by repl.it right now).

https://replit.com/@dsschneidermann/elixir-access-benchmark

I modified the benchmark code in Dogberts answer by adding multiple levels of nesting in structs to make performance of traversal of keys more apparent. The tested structure is `%{sub: %{sub: %{sub: %{key: _}}}}`.

I also added:

1. an benchmark that uses destructuring, which is about 10% faster than access by .key,
   and importantly of note, there is virtually no performance improvement when only
   accessing a single level of .key - only deeply nested structures will see this difference.
2. results for Pathex, which is a library that advertises a 2x-3x
   improvement over Access, which is true as per to the benchmark
   results here. And a significant decrease in memory consumption.

```
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:1] [ds:8:1:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Operating System: Linux
CPU Information: AMD EPYC 7B12
Number of Available Cores: 1
Available memory: 62.80 GB
Elixir 1.12.3
Erlang 24.1.6

Benchmark suite executing with the following configuration:
warmup: 2 s
time: 5 s
memory time: 2 s
reduction time: 0 ns
parallel: 1
inputs: 10000
Estimated total run time: 45 s

Benchmarking .key with input 10000 ...
Benchmarking Access.key with input 10000 ...
Benchmarking Map.get with input 10000 ...
Benchmarking Pathex with input 10000 ...
Benchmarking destruct with input 10000 ...

##### With input 10000 #####
Name                 ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
destruct           17.51       57.11 ms    ±41.05%       64.24 ms      106.27 ms
.key               15.48       64.59 ms    ±39.26%       71.32 ms      158.75 ms
Map.get            13.07       76.51 ms    ±38.02%       78.24 ms      176.67 ms
Pathex              7.39      135.41 ms    ±29.25%      128.66 ms      294.59 ms
Access.key          2.74      365.09 ms    ±15.25%      366.19 ms      520.75 ms

Comparison: 
destruct           17.51
.key               15.48 - 1.13x slower +7.48 ms
Map.get            13.07 - 1.34x slower +19.40 ms
Pathex              7.39 - 2.37x slower +78.30 ms
Access.key          2.74 - 6.39x slower +307.98 ms

Memory usage statistics:

Name          Memory usage
destruct          10.13 MB
.key              10.13 MB - 1.00x memory usage +0.00004 MB
Map.get           10.13 MB - 1.00x memory usage +0.00004 MB
Pathex            36.58 MB - 3.61x memory usage +26.44 MB
Access.key       157.33 MB - 15.52x memory usage +147.20 MB

**All measurements for memory usage were the same**
```